# Tweepy / how to use direct_messages method to get older DMs?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm very very much new to Python and, yea, Tweepy.

I want to, say see the text of all DMs I've received since such-and-such DM.

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = "XXXX"
consumer_secret = "YYY"

access_token = "ZZZ"
access_token_secret = "AAA"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


since_id = "11223344556677889" 
#This is the ID of a month-old DM.  I want to get "all" DMs since then, tho I think I'm limited to 200 per call huh?

direct_messages = tweepy.Cursor(api.direct_messages, since_id=since_id).items()

for dm in direct_messages:
        print dm.text
```

This gives me the most recent 200 DMs. That's not what I want. I want the old DMs, starting with since_id.

FWIW, I know the DM exists, because this returns it properly:

```
dm = api.get_direct_message(since_id)
    print dm.text
```

Comment: Also trying to workaround this issue. I also getting only first 200 DM's. Tried to use max_id param for api.direct_messages, and pass there the id of 200-th message, but I'm getting this 200-th message again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is a twitter API restriction:

> Returns the 20 most recent direct messages sent to the authenticating
>   user. Includes detailed information about the sender and recipient
>   user. You can request up to 200 direct messages per call, and only the
>   most recent 200 DMs will be available using this endpoint.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages